# 'User' object has no attribute 'soft_delete' - Django Soft Deletion

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i have created soft delete in my project and it is working fine. But the problem is that i am using `User` in-built model and `OneToOneField` with `UserProfile`. Now `soft_delete` function is in `UserProfile` Model where im using  `generic.DeleteView` to delete user. The problem is that i could not pass object of `User` to `UserProfile` to set `user_is_deleted` to `True`. Here is my Code.

Views.py

```
class UserDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/user_confirm_delete.html'
    success_url = '/users/'

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.soft_delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def soft_delete(self):
        self.user_is_deleted = True
        self.user_deleted_at  = timezone.now() - tdelta(days=-1)
        self.save()
```

Soft Delete Reference - https://blog.khophi.co/soft-delete-django-quickly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **`delete()`** method as,

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    self.object.userprofile.soft_delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
@classmethod
def soft_delete(self):
    ...
```